# top most window in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form application, i want to it to be the the top most. i use

```
 SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
```

this function, it works fine.But when task manager property always on top is checked it fails. And task manager will appear as the top most window.
         So my concern is, if there any way to achieve it, or we cant not do it with task manager. it will always appear on the top, or anything else i was missing, or doing wrong.

Comment: The Taskmanager is a software that should work always, even if some dumb (I'm not saying that you are dumb!) programer think it would be a great idea to cover the whole screen with a not closeable topmost application. Then the user can still call the task manager and kill this program. That's one of the important usecases of the taskmanager and should not be worked around.

Comment: look my concern is not only about the task manager but the other software like this.

Comment: you can use a timer then set the interval to 1000 then inside the timer.tick set your application as Topmost

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)

Comment: It seems like a weird design idea, but there are situations when this makes sense (and I am not talking about viruses). Imagine a booth at trade fair, where you wish to show your product demo and you don't want to allow people around to terminate your application and surf the internet freely.

Comment: yes thats what i am saying.  I  am not only concern about the task manager because it not a usual behaviour that task manager is set to always on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN say that `HWND_TOPMOST` simply `Places the window above all non-topmost windows.` In other words there are two groups of windows: non-topmost (usual) and topmost and you just sent your window to the other group.

If there is any other topmost window (= task manager in your case), you can switch between them as you normally would between non-topmost windows and they will be overlapping depending on which one is currently active.

If you would like to force your window to be always topmost, I guess you would have to watch for the window deactivation (`WM_ACTIVATE` message) and then move your window up in the Z-order and also focus your window back - this way you would prevent problems like having your window the only one visible, but having the keyboard focus on another window.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if you just want your application is always at the top of other application.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
```